# How can I put tomcat under apparmor?

Tags: tomcat, apparmor

For security reasons, I want to put Tomcat under apparmor. The Ubuntu server(12.04 LTS) guide has a good explanation about apparmor, but I am not sure what is the correct way of creating a profile for Tomcat and how to put it under apparmor.

Answer (score 0):

First install `apparmor-utils` and some extra profiles with:

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils apparmor-profiles
```

Then run:

```
sudo aa-genrpof /usr/bin/tomcat
```

Replacing `/usr/bin/tomcat` with the location of tomcat's binary. genprof will then search the Apparmor profiles for a Tomcat profile. If it doesn't find one it will generate a profile with [`aa-autodep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/aa-autodep.8.html).

After setting a profile you will be asked to start the program you are profiling and use it like you normally would. genprof will monitor the logs for rule violations and allow you to tweak the profile based on what happens. It will then reload all relevant profiles.

Comment: After doing above changes I am still unable to see anything related to Tomcat under apparmor profiles. Please tell me the name of file for tomcat profile.

Comment: Where are you looking for profiles?

Comment: Path for apparmor profiles : "/etc/apparmor.d"

Comment: @SunilRai Where is tomcat's binary located? Do you know? The path to it's profile would be similar.

Comment: Tomcat folder for my application is located at : /home/user/web-portal/tomcat-7.0.27/bin